# How to update test database in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rails-console

I added an entry to the yml fixture for a model. Then `rails console test`. But the new record is not in the database.

How do you "update" the test database to access it in rails console?

Working in Rails 3.0.7, using built-in unit test.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say:

```
bundle exec rake db:fixtures:load RAILS_ENV=test
```